# How to subscribe to the logs from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: c#, logging, mvvm

How to get the logs back to the UI?

I have created a custom Logger `AudittrailLogger` to log to an mssqlserver database. 
Succeeded so far,... logs will be inserted to the database. Now I like to show all the upcoming logs above a certain loglevel in an usercontrol.

Do I have to pass a delegate/action in the configureLoggerFactory method?

```
public void ConfigureLoggerFactory(string dbConnectionString)
{
    if (LoggerFactory == null)
    {
        LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddAudittrailLogger(c =>
        {
            c.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
            c.DbConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
        });
        CaliburnLog = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger("CaliburnMicro");
    }
}
```

In my view currently it looks like:

```
private ILogger Log { get; set; }

public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    ....
    Log = _LogManager.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<MainViewModel>();

    // now I like to subscribe to the logs to show them in the UI
    _LogManager.OnLogReceived += OnLogReceived;
```

Alternatively I write a second custom LoggingProvider. But I'm still lost how I have to send the log message back to the UI.

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
{
    // *** this single line is not working yet *** How to inform the subscribers?
    OnLogReceived?.Invoke(this, new LogReceivedEventArgs(formatter(state, exception), logLevel));

    // save to database via EntityFramework - this could be skipped/deleted in a second LoggingProvider 
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(_Config.DbConnectionString))
    {
        dbContext.LogEntries.Add(new Models.LogEntry()
        {
            TimeStampUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Level = logLevel,
            Source = _Name, 
            EventId = eventId.Id, 
            EventIdName = eventId.Name,
            MachineName = Environment.MachineName,
            UserName = Environment.UserName,
            LogMessage = formatter(state, exception),
            Exception = exception?.Message, 
            StackTrace = exception?.StackTrace
        });
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a static function and static event...

```
public delegate void LogReceived(Object sender, LogReceivedEventArgs args);

public class MyLogManager : Caliburn.Micro.ILog
{
    public static event LogReceived OnLogReceived;

    public static void ShowLog(string msg, LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        OnLogReceived?.Invoke(_Instance, new LogReceivedEventArgs(msg, logLevel));
    }
```

Then in the Log Method just call the static function to initiate the static event.

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
{
    if (logLevel > LogLevel.Debug)
        MyLogManager.ShowLog(formatter(state, exception), logLevel);
```

And in my MainViewModel I just have to subscribe to this event:

```
public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    MyLogManager.OnLogReceived += OnLogReceived;
```